# URL rewrite - issue reading a $_GET variable

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've written an URL rewrite rule to redirect URLs such as

```
http://picselbocs.com/projects/helsinki-map-application/{something} to 
http://picselbocs.com/projects/helsinki-map-application/index3.php?pcode={something}.
```

In the head of the index3.php file I'm checking if the `$_GET['pcode']` variable is set, and my aim is, if the variable is NOT set (i.e. when trying to access `http://picselbocs.com/projects/helsinki-map-application/`), to redirect to the following address: `http://picselbocs.com/projects/helsinki-map-application/D02081460`

Unfortunately, the redirect does not occur. Meaning if the `{something}` value is empty, I'm not redirected to `http://picselbocs.com/projects/helsinki-map-application/D02081460`

The code within the php file is:

```
if (!isset($_GET['pcode'])) {
    header('Location: ./D02081460');    
    exit();
}
```

And the .htaccess file reads:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)?$    index3.php?pcode=$1    [NC,L]
```

Can anyone tell me what it is I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `(.+)?` can (and should) be replaced with `(.*)`. Try that.

Comment: Does the redirect rule actually work? Did you check your Apache logs to see that the GET parameter is actually being passed?

Comment: The rule works as expected unless passing no GET variable, yes. @Truth I've replaced "+" but that still did not do the trick...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, pcode will ALWAYS be set, it just MAY be empty because the rule will always pass and so you will get index3.php?pcode={something}, but {something} could equal to ''.

So either:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$  index3.php?pcode=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^.*                 index3.php             [NC,L]
```

Add a failover and make the group greedy so that it fails if nothing is passed. Or change your check to:

```
if ($_GET['pcode'] == '') {
    header('Location: ./D02081460');    
    exit;
}
```

Hope this helps,

ise

Comment: Thanks, ise! I've made the changes to the rewrite rules and that did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, how could I slightly change the rule so the URLs would start with a question mark? e.g. http://picselbocs.com/projects/helsinki-map-application/?D02081460  ? I've tried for 2 hours and couldn't make it work

Comment: Try escaping the question mark as it's a special character and has a function in regular expressions. Your group can be: ^(\?+[A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$. That work?

Comment: Did you update the Location in header to be: `header('Location: ./?D02081460');`?

Comment: I did, yes. And the .htaccess file looks like this:  
RewriteRule    ^(\?+[A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$    index3.php?pcode=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^.*                 index3.php             [NC,L]